# matching only the first variable with the value

Tags: python, regex

1. x = "  WID 0.12 ;"
2. x = "    WID 0 0.12 0.12 0.12 0.12"
3. x = "    WID 0.2 0.4 0.8 1.6 5 ;"

I want my regexp to match only when `"WID 0.12 ;"` is present in `x`. Otherwise, `re.match` should return 0 (that is no match).

I am using the following:

```
if re.match("\s+WID\s[(\d+)\.(\d+)]", x):
  print x
```

This returns match for all the conditions 1, 2, 3. Can you help me with the expression which returns match only for the first and 0 for others?

Comment: if it has to be 0.12, I'd guess it to be something like ' .*WID\s0\.12.* ' Untested though..

Comment: You are lucky to have been upvoted... You say you want to match `WID .12 ;` and your regex tests for `WIDTH` (note the **TH** ) followed by blanks and a decimal number. Worse, you do not say what can/should happen after the decimal. I'm sorry I cannot guess what you **actually** want.

Comment: Your regex should match _none_ of the three strings, because it requires at least one leading whitespace character, while all three strings start with the letter `'W'`.  I think the regex isn't as you say, or the input strings aren't.

Comment: As a general rule, you should use raw strings for literals that contain regular expressions (`r'regular\s+expression'`, not `'regular\\s+expression'`).  This minimizes the proliferation of backslashes, and more importantly prevent backslashes from being interpreted in surprising ways.

Comment: Finally, what _exactly_ do you want?  You _say_ you want your match to end with a semi-colon, but there is no semi-colon in your regular expression.  You also say you want to match a specific string (`'0.12'`), but your regex appears to be searching for any floating-point number.  I think I trust your regex over your stated intent in the second case, and... I can't tell in the first case.

Comment: Kevin, you are correct, there is spaces before WID. it's somehow not getting captured here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want to know if `"WID 0.12 ;"` is in `x`.

Using `re.match` is like using a bazooka to kill a fly (and it's slow).

This will be enough :

```
if "WID 0.12 ;" in x:
  print x
```

**Edit :**

As the numerical value is not necessary "0.12" (according to a comment below), using regex is justified. This should work :

```
if re.match(" *WID \d+.\d+ ;",x):
  print x
```

Comment: This is not possible in my case. the "0.12" can be any numerical, this is just an example I gave.

Comment: Ok ! So your question wasn't clear on this point. I'm editing my post.

Comment: @hald:  That sort of thing has to be part of your question.  Without it, we can't tell what parts of your string are literal and what parts could be replaced by anything similar (let alone tell what "similar" means to you).  Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37269333/edit) to include required information like this.

Comment: Cromod... Thank you so much.                                                                             if re.match("WID (\d+).(\d+) ;",x):
  print x                                                                                                    This works

Comment: All those parentheses seem unnecessary. (Even if they are, it would make more sense to put them around the entire number.)

Comment: @hald: please mark the correct answer then(due note that my answer was a tad earlier, and equally correct)

Comment: @hald Glad it works for you. But you added spaces in the strings of your question after I proposed this regex (so this no longer works). Please, be more clear for your next question and take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

As I put in my comment, a correct regex is `re.match(".*WID\s(0)\.(12).*", x)` (with matching groups) or `re.match(".*WID\s0\.12.*", x)` (without matching groups).

if you want to match any number combination you can use `re.match(".*WID\s(\d)\.(\d).*", x)`

However, as Tibo says, you can do it with

```
if "WID 0.12" in x:
    print x
```

But this can give a false positive on 0.12x

Comment: You can't simply do it with `if "WID 0.12" in x` as that would also incorrectly match against `"WID 0.125"` for example

Comment: Also he's using capturing group in his example and your answer doesn't give those numbers back

Comment: woops, didn't notice that :) - Edited

Comment: To be more complete, I'd suggest something such as: testing if ``input.startswith('WID 0.12')`` then parsing it with ``nums = [float(x) for x in input.split()[1:]]``, catching ``ValueError`` on the way. Final validation: ``len(set(nums)) == 1 and nums[0] == 0.12``.

Comment: however, it isn't specified if it should start with that value, or if it should just be present. As such, 'in' is a better choice. The rest of your code I should have to run to see how it works
EDIT: ran it; If there are more values in the input string, it will not work as intenden

Answer (score 1):

The square brackets around you capturing groups are causing your errors (and also the fact that you put WIDTH instead of WID)

Your regexp should be:

> WID\s(\d+).(\d+)

Comment: I have corrected the WIDTH to WID for all. I had tried without the square bracket, but still get the same result. Also how do you identify the semicolon (";"). Being special character, this doesn't get captured in the regular expression.

Comment: @hald: The semicolon is not a special character in all regex flavours I know.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments and suggestions. I will take care of the details next time in my post, which lead to confusion with some.

Thanks to cromod (small modifications I made)

```
if re.match("\sWID\s(\d+).(\d+) ;", x):

   print x
```

This works.

Comment: You really should read topics on the help center : [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)